# Set character encoding in jboss-web.xml

Tags: encoding, jboss, character

Is it possible to set character encoding for a JBoss AS 5.1 through a jboss-web.xml cfg file, like this?

```
    <sun-web-app>
    locale-charset-info default-locale="">
    <locale-charset-map locale="" charset=""/>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
    </locale-charset-info>
    </sun-web-app>
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, your config sample is for GlassFish.

If you're still on JBoss AS 5.1, change:

```
<jboss_install>/server/(default)/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml
```

to set the connector URIEncoding:

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

If you're using a later version of JBoss AS or a different application server entirely, see my [complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990314/1594449).