# Bad special character encoding with RESTEasy

Tags: java, rest, encoding, resteasy

I am developing a web application with jboss eap 6.3 which uses resteasy rest framework, I have got a bad encoding problem with special characters passed as FormParam in a POST resources, for example:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
public Response createTask(@FormParam("param") String param) {
    LOGGER.info("HELLO POST XML. "+param);

    return Response.ok(param).build();

}
```

If I pass a thing like abc èèè i will get a stuff like "abc Ã¨Ã Ã¨Ã Ã¨", with jersey rest framework this issue don'exists.

What should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Look for a way to control character encoding - I'd start with changing the character encoding of your request like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708915/detecting-the-character-encoding-of-an-http-post-request

Comment: But in this way i need to force the clients (that could be anywhere of any kind) to check its request, i have this error even if i use the Chrome Advanced Rest Client plugin!! Since this seems a RestEasy problem i can think only to a Server-side solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RESTEasy solution**

Since RESTEasy interprets the request for you using a servlet, your best bet is to use a servlet filter to set the request character encoding:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

  // ...

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

Reference [How to set charset for my web application?](https://developer.jboss.org/message/804018#804018)

**JBoss solution**

To ensure that the application server receives the request parameters in the correct encoding from client requests, you have to configure the connector. For JBoss AS (before version 7) change:

```
<jboss_install>/server/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml
```

or in other JBoss AS versions:

```
<jboss_install>/server/(default)/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml
```

to set the connector URIEncoding:

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Reference [JBoss Seam documentation: 16.1 Internationalizing your app](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/i18n.html#d0e14024).

This configuration is done differently by changing `standalone.xml` in JBoss AS 7 and later, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269362/1594449) (also answered in [JBossDeveloper forum](https://developer.jboss.org/message/643825)).

**Server independent solution**

Since the above is a JBoss dependent solution, my answer would not be complete without providing a server-independent solution.

The most basic is to use a context parameter indicating the character encoding choice for all forms in the application. Setting the context parameter is done in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>PARAMETER_ENCODING</param-name>
  <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then your application can read the context parameter and can set the request character encoding before reading any request parameters. You can set the request encoding in either a Java Servlet or in JSP syntax:

```
<%
  String paramEncoding = application.getInitParameter("PARAMETER_ENCODING");
  request.setCharacterEncoding(paramEncoding);
  String name = request.getParameter("NAME");
%>
```

Reference [Character Conversions from Browser to Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/httpcharset-142283.html#database).

**Database involvement**

You may still have to set the character encoding of your database, otherwise you can lose information as in this diagram:

[image: Database configured for ASCII]

Reference [Character Conversions from Browser to Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/httpcharset-142283.html#database).

**Miscellaneous**

Additional information at [Character encoding JSP -displayed wrong in JSP but not in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374573/character-encoding-jsp-displayed-wrong-in-jsp-but-not-in-url-%C3%A1-%C3%83-%C3%A9-%C3%83%C2%A9) and for Tomcat at [HttpServletRequest - setCharacterEncoding seems to do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing).

You can also [set the default encoding for the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228857/1594449).

A bug titled "[Text responses should default to charset UTF-8](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1066)" was fixed in RESTEasy version 2.3.7.

Comment: The JBoss configuration only affects URI-Parameters - parameters passed in the URI like ```/something?foo=bar``` but not URL-Encoded Parameters passed in the body of a request (FormParams).

Comment: Thanks, i resolver simply adding a filter that sets as utf-8 the character encoding as shown above

Answer (score 3):

I just declared in my project jboss-web.xml default encoding, and this solved the problem

```
<jboss-web>
   <default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>
</jboss-web>
```